# Windows 10 Folder disappeared after renaming

Tags: windows, windows-10

On my F: drive I renamed a folder from "mods" to "modsX" back to "mods". But after doing so, that folder just disappeared.

Im using a rather new HDD.

I tried pressing F5 and checked the recycling bin. Nothing.

After that I treid the `chkdsk` command, but Win10 said, that everything was ok.

Is there a way to get my folder back? I haven't restarted my PC yet.

Comment: Just checking, but did you run Chkdsk specifically on the F: disk? By default it checks C. You may also want to add the /F or /R flag to make it repair anything it finds. These options should force a reboot, and I don't believe a reboot is going to have any effect on your recovery of this folder. You may also want to check the Windows Security to ensure it didn't quarantine your folder. I've had good luck with Disk Investigator to recover accidentally deleted files. While you didn't say you deleted the folder, it may be able to help you find it/recover it back to where you want.

Comment: @JimDiroffII Yeah, I run the command on F: and my Anti-Virus also didnt do anything

Comment: have you tried searching all your drives for any of the contents of the missing directory? Maybe is was moved?

Comment: In folder options do you have hidden files unhidden?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid sadly no

Comment: @Moab sadly yes

Comment: Have you searched the entire drive for that folder name?

Comment: How about trying to create a folder with the same name in the directory. If its hidden somehow there should at least be a notification of a name conflict.

Comment: Also, Do you use McAfee?There has been many posts that seem to say that McAfee or one of it's updates has caused this type of problem